# how to get index of the last selected row from a selection of rows in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have a DataGridView and when I select multiple rows, I want the index of the last selected row. In other words, how to get the maximum most index from a selection of rows.

e.g., if I select row0, row1 and row6, I want the output as "6".

Regards.

Comment: I'd look at what was selected, get the last selected row and retrieve it's index. Based on what you've provided thus far, that's the best answer.

Comment: @Lazarus, but how to do all that. The logic behind that is plain simple. I was looking for the code to see the syntax, to see how it is just got done :(

Comment: @Henk Holterman, let it be anything. Say I have a button, and on click it should show "6" in a messagebox (if i had selected rows as per I explained in my question)

Comment: @nawfal, you missed the point. "Based on what you've provided thus far..." You've asked a vague question which gets you a vague answer. What have you tried and how does it fail? This isn't a shop for free programming resource.

Comment: @nawfa your question and tags should say WinForms, WebForms, WPF, ...

Comment: @Lazarus, I haven't tried anything since I dont know the code. Hence I give my requirement. OK, let me make the question more clear.

Comment: @nawfal, it's a little frustrating that you haven't really even tried. This is really basic code and even if you are a beginner there is no better advice I can offer than to try to work it out for yourself. You'll either succeed or come back with some code of what you've done which we can then use to explain what you missed and from that you'll get really, really valuable knowledge. Someone giving you the answer isn't going to build development skill.

Comment: @Lazarus, Yes I did try, and what I tried was something similar to Bala's answer. I did not say that thinking what I had done isnt all that significant. But the problem being very simple, I dont understand the need for posting it here. Its just a one line code. I felt rather the requirement would do better since its about things as easy as finding a row index. I just miss the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm adding answer for myself. There could be other faster ways, but this works.

```
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.SelectedRows)
                lst.Add(row.Index);

            lst.Sort();
            int i = lst[lst.Count - 1];
```

What this does is add the indexes of all selected rows to an `List<>` and then do a sort and then give the last item from the sorted `List<>`.

Note: the problem with Bala R's method is that, it depends on the order the rows were selected (ie, where the selected pointer lies). It fails when selected rows aren't in an order. It gives the row that was selected last, not necessarily the maximum most index from a selection of rows..

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    int lastIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1].Index;
}
```

Comment: @nawfal I forgot the `.Index` at the end. Fixed now.

Comment: @Bala R, sorry yet again I get this exception. `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: @Bala R, I figured that error out, but your code doesnt seem to give the output as I supposed. Nevertheless tweaking that a bit would yield the perfect answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bala R, the problem with your technique basically is that the output depends on the order the rows/cells have been selected. I mean only bottom to top selection yields the perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Max(row => row.Index);
```

is the same to:

```
var y = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Last().Index;
```

Comment: what could be it in .net 2.0??

Comment: @nawfal: that's LINQ which is only accessible in 3.5 or 4.0. Use regular code by @Bala